# How can I force magnified mode on a retina display?

Tags: macos, retina-display

As [the "High Resolution Explained: Features and Benefits" article describes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html), on a retina display, an "Open in Low Resolution" checkbox is available for the user to open an app if it has problems on a high-res display.

One of our apps apparently has performance issues on retina displays, and we don't have the bandwidth to find and fix the problem immediately. In the mean time, is there a way to automatically disable scaling for the app, so that users don't have to select the checkbox to make the app work properly?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `NSHighResolutionCapable` Boolean defined for `Info.plist`.  I've only seen references in documentation that set this to true, but perhaps the default can also be hard-coded if you set it to false.

Comment: In my tests setting it to false had no effect. As detailed in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426140/how-to-enable-use-low-resolution-on-retina-display-for-an-application-when-shi