# Custom binary runs at low DPI when packaged in .app on macOS

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, installation, sdl

I've created an SDL2 application that has high DPI support and displays correctly when running the compiled binary manually.

I've created a `.app` structure (`Info.plist`, `Contents/...`, etc...) with the compiled binary inside. The app itself launches and runs fine, the problem is that despite adding `NSHighResolutionCapable` to my `Info.plist` the window is presented with a low DPI, contrasting the DPI when launching the compiled binary without the app structure. The `Get Info` menu displays the `Open in Low Resolution` option as ticked and greyed out, I have not touched this option.

Unless there are further steps for macOS app packages required, I can confirm  that there is nothing wrong with the binary itself as it runs at high DPI when ran manually.

Below is a snippet of my `Info.plist`, I've redacted 
a chunk of irrelevant keys for readability sake.

```
[...]
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.0.0</string>
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
```

What changes should do I need to make for running at high DPI?

Comment: Did you just try adding the `NSHighResolutionCapable` key, after running your bundle without it? Did you try resetting the Launch Services DB (see these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426140/how-to-enable-use-low-resolution-on-retina-display-for-an-application-when-shi) or in a new user account?

Comment: @TheNextman Yes, this was it! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was lead in the right direction by [TheNextman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233944/thenextman), it was the simple issue that a previous version of the `Info.plist` was cached before I added the high DPI key.

To update the cache I entered the command `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -f [path to .app]` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20426140/how-to-enable-use-low-resolution-on-retina-display-for-an-application-when-shi).